# Regex on ListDirectoryDetails row

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following example rows:

```
- [RWCE-FM-] nw0113                        8415232 Dec 31  2014 seil12.dat
- [RWCE-FM-] nw0113                       63229952 Jun 30 08:18 prenosdb.dat
- [RWCE-FM-] admin                           16384 Oct 02  2000 monitsml
- [RWCE-FM-] ap                               2101 Jun 16 20:43 za000616.txt
```

From each row, I need to save the file name. However, my regex only runs on first 3 rows, but not on the last one. Does anyone have any ideas?
This is my regex:

```
Regex Name = new Regex(@"\w+\.?\w+\n");
```

Comment: last cast: seil12.dat or prenosdb.dat........

Comment: So why not simply `s.Split().Last()`?

Comment: Your issue is that there is no new line at the end of your file, so it ignores the last file name, is there anyway you can be sure that your file ends with a newline? Alternatively, you might just be better off using Tim Schmelter's suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already guessed from the comments, the main problem is with the `\n` inside your regex that requires a line break `\n` to be after the text you search for. You are not limited to regex to obtain your expected results.

## Regex way

It seems like you only match those texts at the end of the line. You can match them with multiline mode:

```
(?m)\w+\.?\w+\r?$
```

Or

```
(?m)\w+(?:\.\w+)?\r?$
```

Or even (since your expected substrings at the end of the line do not contain spaces):

```
(?m)\S+\r?$
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fm)%5Cw%2B%5C.%3F%5Cw%2B%5Cr%3F%24&i=-%20%5BRWCE-FM-%5D%20nw0113%20%20%20%20%208415232%20Dec%2031%20%202014%20seil12.dat%0D%0A-%20%5BRWCE-FM-%5D%20nw0113%20%20%20%20%2063229952%20Jun%2030%2008%3A18%20prenosdb.dat%0D%0A-%20%5BRWCE-FM-%5D%20admin%20%20%20%20%20%2016384%20Oct%2002%20%202000%20monitsml%0D%0A-%20%5BRWCE-FM-%5D%20ap%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%202101%20Jun%2016%2020%3A43%20za000616.txt)

Perhaps, `(?m)\w+\.?\w+$` will be enough, but in RegexStorm in multiline mode, this `\r?` is required.

[image]

## Non-regex way

```
var res = str.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(p => p.Split().LastOrDefault()).ToArray();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static Regex regex = new Regex(
  "(?<FileName>[^ \\r\\n]+)[\\r\\n]?$",
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
| RegexOptions.Multiline
| RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
| RegexOptions.Compiled
);
```

FileName should have the name of the file.

Comment: IgnoreCase really slows down a regex because its having to baseline all characters. If the pattern really doesn't need that operation (as the one shown)..why add the overhead?

Comment: Right, but if it doesn't run on 2M files, performance will not drop dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern can be simplified even more by simply matching all text that is not whitespace (`[^\s]+`), up to the end of line `\r\n` or end of file marker `$`.

### Example

```
Regex.Matches(text, @"[^\s]+(?:[\r\n]|$)", RegexOptions.Multiline)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select (mt => mt.Value);
```

### Result

[image]

Note that `(?: )` is an anchoring tool, which basically says match the text, but don't capture it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just :

```
static string[] GetFileNames(string[] dirty)
{
   string[] result = new string[dirty.Length]; int index = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < dirty.Length; i++)
   { 
      index = dirty[i].LastIndexOf(' ');
      result[i] = dirty[i].Substring(index + 1, dirty[i].Length - index - 1);
   }
   return result;
}
```

P.S. btw with `Split()` and then `First()` it takes 8 times more CPU ticks to process and it is less efficient. And Regex is even slower.

Check it : [Performance test](http://i.gyazo.com/a03911bf3064688417dce967e7d229b5.png)